# Bulk Update in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, bigdata

For eg, I have a set of document :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c1527c07abb08fc28febe"), "code" : "0001", "time" : ISODate("2014-07-04T09:15:00Z"), "open" : 0, "close" : 0, "high" : 0, "low" : 0, "volume" : 0, "bVolume" : 0, "sVolume" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c1527c07abb08fc28febf"), "code" : "0001", "time" : ISODate("2014-07-04T09:16:00Z"), "open" : 0, "close" : 0, "high" : 0, "low" : 0, "volume" : 0, "bVolume" : 0, "sVolume" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c1527c07abb08fc28fec0"), "code" : "0001", "time" : ISODate("2014-07-04T09:17:00Z"), "open" : 0, "close" : 0, "high" : 0, "low" : 0, "volume" : 0, "bVolume" : 0, "sVolume" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c1527c07abb08fc28fec1"), "code" : "0001", "time" : ISODate("2014-07-04T09:18:00Z"), "open" : 0, "close" : 0, "high" : 0, "low" : 0, "volume" : 0, "bVolume" : 0, "sVolume" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c1527c07abb08fc28fec2"), "code" : "0001", "time" : ISODate("2014-07-04T09:19:00Z"), "open" : 0, "close" : 0, "high" : 0, "low" : 0, "volume" : 0, "bVolume" : 0, "sVolume" : 0 }
```

I would like to retrieve and manipulate them then update them in mongodb. It is running extremely slow with saving each and everyone of them one by one with the function save() in mongoose. By any chance, one could save all of the array in a go? Please mind that each query return almost 300,000 documents. Suggesting a way to loop through them in nodejs without hitting stack overflow (The real stack overflow not the web site :P) would be handy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To perform some manipulation before updating the document, you can use the [Bulk Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) provided in MongoDB. There are two types of the bulk operations:

1. [db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp)
2. [db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp)

In Mongoose, replace the `db` with `model` name and make sure that connection to the `db` is working. Before executing the bulk operation, set the values in the documents either via `update` or using a `callback` if you manipulate based on fetched values.

```
var bulkOperation = Model.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulkOperation.find({<query>}).update({<update>});
bulkOperation.find({<query2>}).update({<update2>});
...and so on.
bulkOperation.execute(function(err) {

});
```

Comment: How do you reference the current document in the update?